# What is the non-transactional behavior of the EVM?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, evm

This question is about Solidity code that **reads** the state of a deployed contract on a Geth node using web3.js. When I call claimsProcessed() with a different account than admin, I expected it to throw my "Security Violation".

Instead it returns a fancy value ...

```
3963877391197344453575983046348115674221700746820753546331534351508065746944
```

I have ...

```
uint256 private claimCount; // == 1    
address admin = 0x123..ce;
```

and ...

```
function claimsProcessed() public adminOnly view returns (uint256)
{
    return claimCount;
}

modifier adminOnly() {
    require (
        msg.sender == admin, "Security Violation - You are not an admin"
    );
    _;
}
```

What can I do to get a "Security Violation" when the read operation is performed by another account than the admins.

Comment: I see a typoo now. Wrong: msg.sender == owner. Correct: msg.sender == admin. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

Functions declared as `view` are usually called off-chain, i.e. outside any block or transaction, and no account is usually involved with the call.  When you calls `claimsProcessed` off-chain, `msg.sender` is unset and your `require` statement always throws.  Fancy number you see is just decimal representation of the first 32 bytes of ABI-encoded error message: `0x8C379A000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.
See the very end of this page for details: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.6/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for spending your time on my question Mikhail. >> your `require` statement always throws -> that is not the case. When I use it with the admin account, then it works as expected.

Comment: OK, if you are calling your method off-chain, but with `from` parameter set to valid admin address, it will not throw.  It looks like Web3 implementation in geth does not translate exception in smart contract executed off-chain into JS exception, so there is no reliable way to distinguish successful execution from unsuccessful one.